# getPropertyValue("backgroundColor") returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, getproperty, getcomputedstyle

This is my problem:

```
var mycss = window.getComputedStyle(myelement);
```

returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object:

```
CSSStyleDeclaration {0: "animation-delay",..., backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",...}
```

[image: console.log(mycss);]

Then, I want to get the background color, but

```
mycss.getPropertyValue("backgroundColor");
```

returns an empty string `""`!

Why??

Comment: try `mycss.getPropertyValue('background-color')`

Comment: I have tried this, it works on firefox, but not works on chrome...

Comment: Try `mycss.backgroundColor`

Comment: On my machine's chrome `getPropertyValue` only works with hyphen spaced arguments

Comment: Like @dartist21 said: https://jsfiddle.net/196tdj3j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your CSSStyleDeclaration, you need to change 'backgroundColor' to 'background-color' and then call

```
mycss.getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

An example:
HTML:

```
<head><style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body">
  hello world
</body>
```

and then calling the getPropertyValue:

```
var mycss = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("body"));
myelement.innerHTML = mycss.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
mycss.getPropertyValue("backgroundColor");
```

use

```
mycss.getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

That worked for me.