# why element.style.backgroundColor property gives an empty string as a result?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".green").style.backgroundColor);
// gives an empty string as a result in console
```

```css
.green {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that I can also use

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".green")).backgroundColor;
```

[which is mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306795/getpropertyvaluebackgroundcolor-returns-an-empty-string)

but I want to know the reason behind this that why it is giving an empty string as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.style` contains only inline styles (set via that property, or the HTML attribute with the same name). It's not affected by style sheets at all. `getComputedStyle` gets you the current effective value for that property, regardless of where it came from.

Answer (score 3):

You want the computed element style:

```
 console.log(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".green"), null).getPropertyValue("background-color"));
```

Comment: Is there is any way that I can get the name of the color as a string instead of the RGB value?

Comment: you can convert rgb to name, check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486730/convert-rgb-to-colorname-string-javascript

Answer (score 1):

As is stated in the [MDN Page for the `element.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style):

> The `style` property is used to get as well as set the ***inline*** style of an element.

Your element does not have a `style` attribute in which the background color is set-- as such, `<yourelement>.style.backgroundColor` returns an empty string.  This is why [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) exists-- to allow you to interrogate the actual final/applied styles on an element, not merely those that might be inline on the element as a `style` attribute.